# Extent of shp files with R for overlapping

Tags: r

I have 2 shapefiles: data (spatial point dataframe) and polys (polygons dataframe). I want to do an overlap but is seems that it does not work.

Here are data and polys:

```
> data
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 12527 
extent      : 10.20075, 20.6108, 54.08669, 57.75905  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
variables   : 3
names       :    timestamp_pretty,     timestamp,     imo 
min values  : 01/04/2006 00:00:55, 1143849655232, 9048392 
max values  : 30/04/2006 23:59:36, 1146441576823, 9191541 
> polys
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 436375 
extent      : 4210000, 5441000, 3395000, 4813000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
variables   : 2
names       :    Id, Count 
min values  :     0,     0 
max values  : 99999,     9
```

to manage the overlapping, I use

```
proj4string(data) <- proj4string(polys)                            # to confirm the same reference system
inside <- !is.na(over(data, as(polys, "SpatialPolygons")))    # overlapping shape file and data
```

and then `mean(inside)` to check the average of points in polys.

But there is nothing happening, mean is always 0. I used this many times before and it always work, I guess it does not work not because the extent of the 2 sph files are  different.

Is there a way to edit this?

Comment: It is not enough to set the CRS via `proj4string(data) <- proj4string(polys)`. You need to transform one of the data to ensure identical CRS. `data <- spTransform(data, CRS(proj4string(polys)))` should do.

Comment: @TimSalabim But following the description of data and polys, the CRS is already the same one, no?

Comment: Looking at the coordinates we see that even though the CRS is the same, the coordinates of data seem to be in longitude & latitude. Hence, none of the points are located inside any of the polygons. is the data excerpt you show above before or after you set the `proj4string`? If this is the raw data, then you can try to set `proj4string(data) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")` before the transformation. If the raw data are ok, then you need to do the transformation INSTEAD of setting the CRS via `proj4string`.

Comment: @ TimSalabim, the data excerpt is after ´proj4string(data) <- proj4string(polys)´. I will continue to try...

Comment: Ok, then just replace `proj4string(data) <- proj4string(polys)` with `data <- spTransform(data, CRS(proj4string(polys)))` and things should work.

Comment: @TimSalabim, if I do so (to replace), I have the following error ´Error in spTransform(xSP, CRSobj, ...) : 
  No transformation possible from NA reference system´ because does not have a CRS... very tricky!

Comment: then try setting `proj4string(data) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")` before the transformation. If this is ESRI shapefile(s) they should come with .prj file that has the CRS information. It happened to me frequently that I forgot to copy that together with the other files.